# List Google App Users and handle Select\Update\Delete operations on users Drive using Admin account(.NET)

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, google-apps, google-drive-api

Does any one know

1. How to get list of users and groups from Google Apps Account? (with some APIs which are not deprecated now)
2. Perform basic operations on files inside any normal users Drive account using Administrator account of Google APPs using Google Drive SDK in **.NET**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use the Provisioning API to retrieve the list of users and groups in a Google Apps domain: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/

2) Check Google Apps domain-wide Delegation of authority: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

Comment: I think this Provisioning APIs are under Google Data APIs which are now deprecated by Google? am I correct or I can still use this APIs?

Comment: The Provisioning API and in general Google Data APIs are not deprecated. Some of those APIs have newer versions based on the new discovery mechanism (e.g. Calendar API) and you should use them when possible, but the documentation will clearly mark them as deprecated when that is the case.

Comment: How to initialize the AppsService object of Provisioning API from Google Drive API?  I have tried with authentication token but always getting 'Invalid Token' exception. 
AppsService _appServ = new AppsService("DomainName", "AuthenticationToken");